# Swiffy, flash to HTML5 works locally but not on a server

Tags: html, flash, google-swiffy

I have tried numerous attempts at converting flash files to HTML5 with Swiffy -- and they all work great in a browser running locally, but when I put the HTML file that is exported on a server (I tried two separate ones, just in-case it was some server configuration) they do not run, it gives a blank white screen.

I tried saving the file down to Flash 5 export, and changed settings and they work locally but not when placed on a server. I tried converting several flash files all with different animations, and I get the same results -- it works locally but not on a server. Has anyone had this issue or knows how to resolve ?

Comment: are we supposed to guess what the issue is ? maybe it has nothing to do with Swiffy , how can we know if you dont provide anything to start with ?

Answer (score 0):

The most common explantation is that there are links within the files you uploaded that no longer point to the correct place. Use your browser's console to see if there are any errors flagged up. Failing that, look through all the uploaded files and check manually.

P.S. Post a link.